# Something in python similar to index method for multiple ocurrences

Tags: python, function, methods, indexing

Is there some function in python that does that the `index()` method does but considering multiple occurrences? I know for strings there is also the `rfind()`method, which kind of helps, but nothing for lists.

P.S.: I know you can use list comprehensions and there are thousands of examples of that, but I'm looking for a pre-defined function that is intrinsic to python or that can be obtained via some package.

Comment: I don't think so. What is wrong with an own two-line wrapper function?

Comment: What's wrong with `def find_indexes(lst, value):
    return [dx for dx, item in enumerate(lst) if item == value]`?

Comment: Nothing's wrong, I just think that this is such a simple and general task that there must already exist something that does it.

Comment: Why do you think finding indexes that match a value a common task?  I don't recall needing something like this.

Comment: The Python standard libs are pretty big, so it's hard to definitively answer "no" to this... But anecdotally, I have never heard of an existing function that does what you want.

Comment: I honestly do not understand the down votes. I've done my research, I still have a doubt about the existence or not of something and I am sharing  this doubt here. I don't think that the fact that one doesn't think that question is relevant for his interests should justify a down vote. I have needed this plenty of times and have always resorted to list comprehensions. What's wrong with wondering if there's another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As Steven pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543297/something-in-python-similar-to-index-method-for-multiple-ocurrences#comment47238488_29543297), and as you already know,

```
def find_indexes(lst, val):
    return [i for i,v in enumerate(lst) if v == val]
```

would work. If you don't like using a function instead of an object's own method, you could build an own class for this:

```
class MultiIndexList(list):
    def multi_index(self, val):
        return [i for i,v in enumerate(self) if v == val]
```

Then you could use it like

```
>>> lst = MultiIndexList((1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2))
>>> lst.multi_index(1)
[0, 3, 9]
```